# fwrite C programming

Tags: c

HI...i want to write something like this in a file, using fwrite

```
fwrite("name is %s\n",name, 60, fp);
```

but  is not working, only write in the file the string. any idea?

Comment: The first step to writing a C program (or any program, for that matter), is to actually look at the API documentation instead of just throwing random arguments at it and hoping it will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean `fprintf`?

```
fprintf(fp, "name is %s\n", name);
```

[`fwrite`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/) is designed mainly for writing raw binary data into a file, not text output. For text output it's more natural to use `fprintf`, `fputs`, `fputc` etc.

---

If you really need `fwrite`, you have to separate the `name` part out, like:

```
fwrite("name is ", 1, 8, fp);
fwrite(name, 1, strlen(name), fp);
fwrite("\n", 1, 1, fp);
```

Comment: Another method is to use `sprintf` to a buffer, then use `fwrite` to write the buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Better yet, at the bash prompt, do

```
$ man fwrite
```

If on Windows, or a system without manpages installed, point a browser at http://linuxmanpages.com/

Seriously, the sooner you get familiar with manpages, the easier learning C will become.